# How to create a spring boot site admin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend

I am doing a small RESTfull API tutorial project as an information portal. I wrote the front by myself (html + css + js + a little burstrap). Rest chose because of the increasing popularity, since studying, then learning what is needed at the current time.
In general, I will pass to the essence of the problem: a site is a few pages with articles, general information, pictures, etc. - in short, nothing supernatural, and there is no magic logic. I decided to implement an administrator, because someone has to edit these articles, and then I rested.
I don’t understand how to implement it correctly? All I found was about spring security and the distribution of roles to users, but I don't need any users, I only need the site admin. How is this implemented correctly? Which way should I look?
P.S. Several people advised me not to use spring for this, but to take something simpler, such as django or flask, but I am studying Java and would like to master spring.

Answer (score 1):

How about considering spring boot admin https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/ ?

I also used spring boot admin. it is powerful

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think this is even more complicated than what I want to do. I just need to somehow add an administrator, someone who could edit articles on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a coding question, it's an application design question.

The solution is actually embedded in your question,

> All I found was about spring security and the distribution of roles to users

You can create a page from which the admin can log in and edit whatever needed, you will have to design the admin panel and stuff like that.

The users' creation and login mechanism is a well-documented subject.
check [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-5-form-login-with-database-provide) for example.

Check this for the [JWT](https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-security-tutorial) solution.

Comment: thanks to you too, but you see, I have REST, in which case spring security needs to be configured in a completely different way, and I cannot figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by REST? the example I provided also uses REST operations to check the user and the credentials and to provide a token. Can you please explain your problem in detail in the post?

Comment: REST - it means that communication between the server and the client goes through json files, not the display of models. Those. each @RestController returns a json file with information.

Comment: Yes my friend I get your point, you can Spring security with JWT. The JWT token will be included in the requests' header to allow authentication. Please check the updated link in my answer.